# How can I get a Google Visulization LineChart to display vertical gridlines?

Tags: linechart, gridlines

I am using javascript to display a Google Visulization LineChart in my web application. How can I get it to display vertical gridlines? I've read about using chg to set them, but as far as I know that only applies when making the chart using the query string method. Could you tell me how to get verticle gridlines when initialising the LineChart as follows:

`new google.visualization.LineChart(div.get(0)).draw(data, {
                                title: 'Unique visitors - Previous Month',
                                width: div.width(),
                                height: 330,
                                chartArea: {left:50, width:"90%"},
                                legend: 'none',
                                yAxis: {title: '(thousands)'}
                            });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ScatterChart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart.html) with a positive `lineWidth` to emulate a line chart. This component supports vertical grid lines through the `hAxis.gridlineColor` setting.

Comment: the down side is that ScatterChart requires an integer values on axeses