# Google AreaChart not displaying Vertical Gridlines.

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Firstly, I have checked these out:

- [How can I get a Google Visulization LineChart to display vertical gridlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745059/how-can-i-get-a-google-visulization-linechart-to-display-vertical-gridlines)
- [Google Chart: AreaChart vAxis Gridlines is Not Drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187422/google-chart-areachart-vaxis-gridlines-is-not-drawing)

And they don't seem to be quite what I'm looking for so hopefully this isn't a duplicated question.

I am having trouble adding gridlines to a Google AreaChart vertical axis. I have used:

```
 vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        gridlines: {
            color: '#f3f3f3',
            count: 5
        }
    }
```

But it doesnt seem to be working, When I change the value of vAxis Count: It adds lines to the hAxis :(

see : http://jsfiddle.net/j29Pt/2/

**Can anyone solve this?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As I understand it vAxis is for vertical axis and vAxis.gridlines is for horizontal lines. 

It seems that you have problem with hAxis.gridlines. This [link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart) says that: "This option is only supported for a continuous axis." So, you have to figure it out how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your x-axis to a continuous data type (number, date, datetime, timeofday) to get the vertical lines.  the `hAxis.gridlines.count` option controls how many vertical gridlines you get.  `vAxis.gridlines.count` controls how many horizontal lines you get.

In your example, you could change you DataTable to this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', ],
    [2004, 1000],
    [2005, 1170],
    [2006, 660],
    [2007, 1030]
]);
```

and your options to this:

```
var options = {
    title: '',
    hAxis: {
        title: 'Year',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#333'
        },
        gridlines: {
            color: '#f3f3f3',
            count: 4
        },
        format: '####'
    },
    vAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
        gridlines: {
            color: '#f3f3f3',
            count: 5
        }
    }
};
```

see example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/j29Pt/3/

Comment: how we add month in hAxis?